# React Select mapping issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm using [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) in my project and I'm using it within a `map` like that:

```
renderItems() {
  this.props.items.map(item => (
    <Select
      id="options"
      value={this.state.optionSelected}
      onChange={this.onChangeOption}
      options={this.showOptions()}
    />
  );
}
```

It show correctly all my options for all my items but now I can not get rid about the select...

Basically when I select an option on a single item, that option is changing for all items...

This is what i did so far:

```
onChangeOption(e) {
  this.setState({ optionSelected: e.value });
}
```

How can I adjust it to change the option only on the one I wish to change it?

Thanks

Comment: it changes all because they are all dependant on single variable.

Comment: That's ok... but how can I solve it?

Comment: Make each of them be dependant on different variable

Comment: If you have a unique identifier for each item (for example id) you can update the state of the particular item, not all of them.

Comment: Since it is dynamic, can you please answer the question showing an example of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same change handler for all of your select components and then set the same state value for all your select components. To deal with this either you need to separate your select components with a container component that handles their own state and change event or you need to give each select component a unique state value.

**Example**

```
renderItems() {
  this.props.items.map(item => (
    <Select
      id="options"
      value={this.state.optionSelected[item.id]}
      onChange={(event) => this.onChangeOption(event, item.id)}
      options={this.showOptions()}
    />
  );
}

onChangeOption(event, itemId) {
  this.setState((prevState) => { 
    const prevStateClone = Object.assign({}, prevState);
    prevStateClone.optionSelected[itemId] = event.target.value;
    return prevStateClone;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making `optionSelected` string variable, make it as array in state.
Now do the following.

```
renderItems() {
  this.props.items.map(item, index => (
    <Select
      id="options"
      value={this.state.optionSelected[index]}
      onChange={(selectedValue) => this.onChangeOption(selectedValue, index)}
      options={this.showOptions()}
    />
  );
}

onChangeOption(selectedValue, index) {
  const optionSelected = this.state.optionSelected.slice() // slicing to get new copy of optionSelected instead of referencing to old one which causes mutation 
  optionSelected[index] = selectedValue
  this.setState({optionSelected: optionSelected})
}
```

What you were doing is using a single variable to hold values of the select box. So if anyone changes, it will reflect all select box

Answer (score 0):

Try [cloning the object to a new object](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or if this `optionSelected` is a class, you can implement a constructor that clones it for your like:

```
export class optionSelectedClass {
    myfield = '';

    constructor(fields){
        this.myField = fields.myField;
    }
}
```

or even

```
export class optionSelectedClass {
    myfield = '';

    constructor(fields){
        for (let f in fields) {
            if (!this[f]) {
                this[f] = fields[f];
            }
        }
    }
}
```